# Removerange method after the use of take method from the list<T> has unexpected behavior

Tags: c#

Does anyone knows why the length after leaving the while loop body in the below code is zero? Please do not provide me chunking algorithm I am already aware of several such algorithms and I know how to solve this problem. My question is only about the wired behavior of RemoverRange or perhaps Take.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }

    var chunks = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();

    while (list.Count > 0)
    {
        chunks.Add(list.Take(10));
        list.RemoveRange(0, 10);
    }

    int length = chunks.ToList()[0].Count();
}
```

Comment: LINQ is effectively a view. It holds onto the `list` collection, and only iterates the collection when you call `.Count()`.

Comment: `list.Take` won´t return a `List`, but simply an **iterator** which yields to *deferred execution*. You´d have to call `list.Take(10).ToList()` in order to fore an *immdediate execution*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the following line:

```
var chunks = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
```

you create a list, whose `Count` is 0, since there aren't any items in the list. Then at the `foreach` statement at each step you add `list.Take(10)` and after this you Remove the first 10 items from `list`. The **important** this here is to realize that `list.Take(10)` is *lazy evaluated* (more often you will hear the term *deferred execution*). The time that this would first be evaluated is at the following line:

```
int length = chunks.ToList()[0].Count();
```

At this line `list.Take(10)` would be evaluated and since you have removed all the items form the `list`, there aren't any elements in `list`. For this reason, `list.Take(10)` return an empty sequence and consequently the `chunks.ToList()[0]` would be an empty list.

**Update** *deferred execution explanation*:

Let that we have the following list:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var firstThree = list.Take(3);
```

The variable `firstThree` holds a reference to an enumerator - specifically an `IEnumerable<int>`. It does not hold an array or a list of 1,2,3. The first time you will use this iterator you will start to "fetch" data from the `list`.

For instance you could call the `ToList` or `ToArray` methods:

```
var firstThreeList = firstThree.ToList();
var firstThreeArray = firstThree.ToArray();
```

Both the above calls would put the iterator in action - in general terms would force the execution of your query in LINQ -. At this very moment, you will traverse the `list` and you will fetch the first three items.

That being said, it is clear that if in the meanwhile you have modified the `list` by removing all the numbers from `iist`, there wouldn't be any elements in the `list` and you will get nothing.

As a test I would suggest you run the above code once and then run it again **but** before `ToList` and `ToArray` calls to make this call:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => true);
```

You will notice now that both `firstThreeArray` and `firstThreeList` are empty.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I am not sure if I understood right. Can you please explain a little bit more

Comment: @AydinHomay You are very welcome ! Sure thing, will do.

Comment: Thanks it was a very nice explanation, I have seen that the Take method in dot net source is using yield return but I was not enough attentive to catch the point.

Comment: @AydinHomay You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're experiencing is that LINQ is kind of like a view. It only actually iterates through the collection when you call a method that requires it to produce a specific value (`First()`, `Last()`, `Count()`, etc.). So the list is only evaluated at the point where you call one of these methods.

```
chunks.Add(list.Take(10));
```

This code effectively says "take a reference to `list`, and when somebody iterates you, only go as far as the first 10 items". To resolve this, you can convert that small section to a list (evaluate those 10 items, and create a new list from them):

```
chunks.Add(list.Take(10).ToList());
```

Consider this code:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
IEnumerable<string> skip2 = names.Skip(2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", skip2)); // "c"
names.Add("d");
names.Add("e");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", skip2)); // "c, d, e"
```

Because you use the iterator (`IEnumerable<string> skip2`) each time you call `string.Join(", ", skip2)` it will iterate through the list each time, even if the list has changed.

As such, you will get `"c"` on the first run, and `"c, d, e"` on the second run.

In fact, this would be perfectly valid (although harder to read):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<int> values = list.DefaultIfEmpty(0);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(10);
list.Add(15);
Console.WriteLine(values.Average()); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
chunks.Add(list.Take(10));
```

does not actually take 10 items from `list`, it only tells to take 10 when `chunks[i]` is first referenced (through e.g. `Count()`). Since you are altering the list, the reference points to an empty list. You can force the evaluation of the list using

```
chunks.Add(list.Take(10).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no weird behaviour at all. That is exactly the expected behaviour for `IEnumerable`. What you should keep in mind is that `IEnumerable` is lazily evaluated, which means it is evaluated when is enumerated, i.e when you actually access the said `IEnumerable`. What you are doing is basically→

①Get the reference to `list` object
②Prepare to take the first 10 elements of the said `list` object, *do not yet evaluate!*
③Add the `not yet evaluated` object, in this case→`(LINQ.Take(10))` into `chunks` list.
④Remove the first 10 elements of `list`
⑤Rinse and Repeat until there are no more items in `list`
⑥Create a list, which is all made up `not yet evaluated` items of `list.Take(10)`.
⑦You take the first element of the said `chunks`, which is `not yet evaluate` but is a reference to the first 10 elements of `list`, which is empty!!!
⑧You call `Count` on IEnumerable instance, which finally evaluates the first ten elements of an enmpy `list`